# Should I create a table to track instances of "missing" records?

Tags: mysql, database, system-analysis

I have a table called `student` and it has the following fields:

`idno(primary), lastname, status, password, syearid(foreign)`

My problem is I have to store the unvoted students in each school_year(syearid):

[image: sample]

I have a table that stores students who have already voted.  How should I track the unvoted students?  Should I make another table?. One of my problems is when the student registers in school_year (2015) or syearid (2000) and votes it will create a student vote record, when student again votes for the next school_year it will create another record in the student votes table but my question is how to store an unvoted student if the student can register only once in a life time (primary is my idno so student can no longer register again but the school_year of the student is the same when she/he registered). What should I do?

Comment: multiple columns primary key? Add a 0/1 column for voted/not voted? I don't really understand what you wrote though.

Comment: the school year is my problem when student registered like 2015 and voted from that year, it will save to other table that will handle the candid,idno,syearid , syearid will handle that student already voted, and that's not a problem cause it has a table that will handle student already voted but I have no records for the student who didn't vote a year

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to explicitly store records of students that didn't vote for a given year.  You can simply join students to the vote table and check for null.  Students without vote records for a given year will not have voted.  I'm assuming the `syearid` in the student votes table is the voting year and `syearid` in the students table is the year the student started school.

```
SELECT s.* FROM student s
LEFT JOIN student_votes sv ON (s.idno = sv.idno AND sv.syearid = 2015)
WHERE sv.syearid IS NULL
```

Also, assuming only students from certain years are eligible to vote

```
SELECT s.* FROM student s
LEFT JOIN student_votes sv ON (s.idno = sv.idno AND sv.syearid = 2015)
WHERE sv.syearid IS NULL 
AND s.syearid IN (2012, 2013, 2014, 2015)
```